# is there any way to add google play services 9.0.2 to an Eclipse project?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to add Google Play Service Libraries to my Android Project in Eclipse. I need a version > 9.0.0.

Comment: Dont use Eclipse to make and Android app. Use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). 

`Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended`

Comment: If you must use Eclipse, download the Andmore distribution and use proper Gradle dependencies.

Comment: @GaryJohnson Or IntelliJ IDEA if you don't want to limit yourself to Android projects.

Comment: [Eclicpse is no longer officially supported for Android Development](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html). Using Eclipse may be preventing you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it, i used Google Play Services  (r29) in my recent app, because latest one and the one you mention will be of **no use** in Eclipse as it will lack ***libProjects*** which we import as a library to use in our Application Project and  ***integer*** value of Google Services version which we have to use in *Android Manifest* under `<meta-data />`

Steps to do :

1- Download Google Play Services ([r29](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8487000_r29.zip)) rev30+ will have just documentation and sample projects which are of no use.

2- Unzip downloaded rar and paste in directory `X:\yourSDKdirectory\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\`

3- Go to Eclipse `File->Import->Existing Android Code->android-sdk\extras\google\ google_play_services\libproject`

4- Now you can use this project as library in your Android Application Project.

5- In **Android Manifest** after `<application >` tag

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope this helps.!

***Short Advice***:

It is better to switch to Android Studio, despite all hate i have against Android Studio, i had to switch, it is better in some ways but in most, it is literally crap as compared to Eclipse. But with little tweaks and management you will find it smooth but still irritating, well switch to it, after 4~5 years it might become as efficient and optimized as Eclipse :D

2.2 (Preview 6 is quite good, 7 is out though)

Comment: this coment will not bring somthing new to this answer but I'm with you Muhammad Faisal Hyder. I prefere 100 times mor eclipse then Android Studio